# regex filter for list of words until nth occurence of character

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, filter

I have a Dataframe with urls. I have a blacklist with words to filter these urls. 
No I want to filter these urls until the third occurence of `/`. 
So for example:

http://example.com/abc/def/

Here I would like to filter only until the third occurence of `/`.

So just:
http://example.com/

I read some similiar questions and I guess I need to combine two regexes.

1. `/.*?/(.*?)/` this should do the job for filtering until the third occurence of `/`
2. to filter the for a list of words I use this expression:

```
mask = df["url"].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(blacklist)))
df_new = df[~mask]
```

Now I don't know how to combine these two expressions. I'm new to Python and especially regex so there also might be a smarter way of doing this task.

Thank you.

EDIT:
Blacklist looks like this: `["ebay","shop","camping","car"]`

Df like this:

```
url                             text
http://example.com/abc/def/     fdogjdfgfd
http://abcde.com/yzt/egd/        oijfgfdgdf
http://ebay.com/buy/something    fgfgeg
```

Comment: Give the example of your blacklist words as well as few of the urls in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the part of the url up to the third `'/'` and then use you logic on this:

```
mask = df["url"].str.extract(r'((?:[^/]*/[^/]*){,3})').str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(blacklist)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with the given regex pattern:

```
pattern = '|'.join(rf'(?://[^/]*?{b}[^/]+)' for b in blacklist)
m = df['url'].str.contains(pattern, case=False)
df = df[~m]
```

---

```
# print(df)
                           url        text
0  http://example.com/abc/def/  fdogjdfgfd
1    http://abcde.com/yzt/egd/  oijfgfdgdf
```

You can test the regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/30MSxL/1).